# Managing lightboxes and the content within them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to find a better way of managing lightboxes with JS. I'm working in a Rails environment.

I usually put the HTML for lightboxes in my Rails application layout file, then I would simply use JS to show / hide these lightboxes when needed - this is very static. Sometimes I would use jQuery to create the lightbox and the content within it on the fly and then show and hide that, very messy.

Should I be using JS templates for this? I think I want to have several templates that contain different content for lightboxes - with the ability to output variables in these templates.

What's the best way to maintain several lightboxes of different widths / heights and content?

Answer (score 1):

I would abstract your lightbox completely (not put any html for them into the layout), but generate the whole thing on the fly and append it to body or specified element.  As far as storing lightboxes of different dimensions, I suppose it depends what lightbox you are using.  A lot of them allow you to pass a config object, which controls things like dimensions, etc.  This is probably the best way to do it because you will be reusing the same code, just specifying different dimensions for it.

Comment: Could you give me a code example? Finding it hard to visualize.

Comment: Say if I wanted to show a form with a lot of fields inside a lightbox, would you create the form with all the inputs, append it to the lightbox and display it? I was just thinking it would be a lot of JS code, as I will have a few more lightboxes - some with forms, some without.

Comment: Since you're using Rails, you can store your info in partials and just render them inside the lightbox.  I'm a bit rusty with Rails, but in jQuery you can use the .html() command to load the htm fragment.

Comment: So the lightbox itslef can be generated on the fly with a config file to specify the size of the container, presence/absence of elements, etc, and the content will be an html from a partial.

Comment: I think I will try out the partials method first, it'll save a lot of JS :)